# Django adding url.py with Django-batchimport 404 error

Tags: python, django-admin

I have created a very basic Djangodb where I am trying to do a batch import of several thousand excel files that I have. In the process of researching the best way to database all of these files I found this: https://github.com/pstch/django-batchimport

I have read through the installation documentations, and on the last step of adding the urls to the url.py file I keep getting a 404 error for both my localhost/admin and localhost/batchimport.

Here is the code for url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from batchimport import *
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'export.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    (r'^batchimport', include('batchimport.urls')),
)
```

and here is my code for urls.py in my batchimport folder.

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from views import ImportUploadView, ImportOptionsView, ImportRunView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^upload/$',
                           ImportUploadView.as_view(),
                           name='batchimport_upload'),
                       url(r'^options/$',
                           ImportOptionsView.as_view(),
                           name='batchimport_options'),
                       url(r'^run/$',
                           ImportRunView.as_view(),
                           name='batchimport_run'), )
```

Here is the output from the error that I am getting:

```
ImportError at /admin/ cannot import name related 
Request Method: GET 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ 
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: cannot import name related 
Exception Location: /Users/USER/Development/ExportOCC/export/batchimport/utils.py
in <module>, line 5 Python
Executable: /Users/USER/anaconda/bin/python Python
Version:    2.7.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import is not available in Django 1.8. You can give it a try and import `related` from the original source. Change `batchimport/utils.py` like:

```
from django.db.models import get_model
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField, related
```

If that works, please also notify the author of django-batchimport!

Comment: I made the changes to batchimport/utils.py and it allowed me to access /admin but when I try /batchimport I get: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/batchimport
Using the URLconf defined in export.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^batchimport/
The current URL, batchimport, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Add a `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Klaus D.,  Thanks for your help, but i've tried adding the `urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^batchimport/', include('batchimport.urls')),    
)` ... But I still get a 404 error on localhost/batchimport; However, /admin works properly.